# Ionic 5 and Capacitor target android 4.4 (API 19)

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic-native, capacitor, ionic5

I have created an app with ionic5 and capacitor. I'm jutst able to install it in Androids with APIs equal or bigger than  21. Is it possible to some how install it in Android 4.4 ?

I googled and found out that if it was created with Cordova, it was possible to make some changes in config.xml. But couldn't find something about Capacitor. Also I found [this article](https://ionicframework.com/blog/thanks-to-capacitor-ive-fallen-in-love-with-mobile-development-again/) about converting Cordova app to capacitor and in it is mentioned that in case I convert Cordova to Cpacitor, I can make some changes in capacitor.config.js file somethign like this:

```
// capacitor.config.json
{
  "cordova": {
    "preferences": {
      "ScrollEnabled": "false",
      "android-minSdkVersion": "19",
   }
}
```

I tried that but again I was not able to install my app in Android 4.4 and got this error: INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK

I like to know is it possible to achieve this goal with Capacitor or it just work in Corcova? 
If it just works in Crdova, can I change my app from Capacitor to Cordova? 
I think it is necessarily to have asolution for that because around 4% of Android users, use Android 4.4 which is not less.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not possible, Capacitor only supports Android 5+ (API 21+)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How if I change my app to Cordova? Does it support API 19?

Comment: yes, current cordova version still supports API 19, but next release will be out in a few days/weeks and will only support API 22+, so make sure you don't update

Comment: So because I always prefer to update everything, I think it would be better that I stick in Capacitor then I don't need to make a lot of changes in my project. Thank you for your answer.